# Slow move on Windows samba client when directory contains many small files

Tags: windows, performance, samba

I have a Samba share mounted on a Windows client and from the client, when I move a directory containing ~2500 small files totaling around 1.5TB, it takes almost a minute.

Why is this not instantaneous?

- The same operation locally on the Linux server [ext4] happens instantaneously
- We are managing the permissions completely from Windows and Mac clients using ACLs

```ini
# smb.conf

[global]
        workgroup = XYZ
        security = ads

        passdb backend = tdbsam

        #log level = 3 winbind:5
        log level = 1
        socket options = TCP_NODELAY IPTOS_LOWDELAY
        server multi channel support = yes
        interfaces ="192.168.123.12;capability=RSS,speed=40000000000"
        aio read size = 1
        aio write size = 1
        aio max threads = 128
        max stat cache size = 1048576
        case sensitive = yes

        kerberos method = secrets and keytab
        realm = XYZ.EXAMPLE.COM
        template homedir = /home/%U@%D
        password server = dc1.xyz.example.com
        template shell = /bin/bash
        idmap config IYC : range = 2000000-2999999
        idmap config IYC : backend = rid
        idmap config * : range = 10000-999999
        idmap config * : backend = tdb
        winbind use default domain = no
        winbind refresh tickets = yes
        winbind offline logon = yes
        winbind enum groups = no
        winbind enum users = no
        map acl inherit = yes

        vfs objects = acl_xattr fruit streams_xattr
        acl_xattr:ignore system acls = yes

        store dos attributes = no
        map archive = no

        fruit:metadata = stream
        fruit:model = MacSamba
        fruit:posix_rename = yes
        fruit:veto_appledouble = no
        fruit:nfs_aces = no
        fruit:wipe_intentionally_left_blank_rfork = yes
        fruit:delete_empty_adfiles = yes

[footage]
        path = /data/footage
        read only = no

[projects]
        path = /data/projects
        read only = no
```

Comment: Is the server using RAID, or are you moving between different hard drives?
Also could check if the client has huge network traffic when moving.

Comment: @hatalmasalma - server is using RAID6 12 SSD drives. mv is between folders on the same array. There is no other traffic on the network. mv happens instantaneously when doing it directly on the linux system

Comment: "There is no other traffic" - I meant if there is a spike in traffic when copying, then that could mean the data gets transferred to the client and back. Other than that, I don't have ideas, I hope others can help.